# Finding duplicated data using Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data files which contains "name,time,data" column, I'd like to find out duplicated data (name, time must exactly similar, and data (if any binary data "1" match regardless the position). For example, data below:
Is there any available function can do this?

For example:

```
name,time,data
tg,0x34,1111
ab,0x54,1011
k,0x34,0100
c,0x34,0001
e,0x34,0000
d, 0x34,1111
```

duplicated result:

```
tg,0x34,1111
k,0x34,0100
c,0x34,0001  
d, 0x34,1111
```

Comment: how is the deduped result a valid one?

Comment: I'm confused. So we are deleting any rows that doesn't have a duplicate in the `time` column? Generally, for this kind of data manipulation though, I'd suggest looking at `pandas`.

Comment: You want all the rows where just the second column is the same?

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin, yes, only duplicated result will be printed out, I looked at pandas, it can only check for "exactly match" situation that means (1111=1111),  but I couldn't find any available function that can check if any binary match regardless position (eg: 1111=1000,0100,1100)

Comment: @wwii, yes, the second column same, and match any "1" in the binary data, for example: even the second column is the same, but this case is not consider as duplicated: a,0x34, 0000 should be printed out as duplicated for tg, 0x34,1111

Comment: @AlexFung, the valid one shouldn't have any duplicated result in the data files, we need to find out the duplicated results, and do another step to determine which combination is valid

Comment: @user37970 `pandas` has much more than that. You can probably achieve what you need using methods like `apply()`.

Comment: are ```a,0x34, 0001``` and ```tg,0x34, 1000``` duplicates of each other?

Comment: I agree with @Posh_Pumkin.   With the apply function you could map to anything you want and then use duplicated to get the results you wanted.  Could you explain a little more what about the binary data?  Is this more of a checksum that needs to add to the same number?

Comment: @wwii, a & tg is not duplicates of each other because the position of 1 doesn't match, if tg=1111, then a=0001, then this is the duplicated case because the position of 1 is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a sorting, grouping, comparing problem.  Not really sure why but I opted for a class that has methods needed for sorting, grouping and comparing. ... Python 2.7 code:

Setup;

```
import io, collections, operator, csv

s = '''name,time,data
tg,0x34,1111
ab,0x54,1011
k,0x34,0100
c,0x34,0001
e,0x34,0000
d,0x34,1111'''

# for file emulation
f = io.BytesIO(s)
```

Class to *hold* the info and work with Python tools

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name = None, time = None, data = None):
        self. name = name
        self.time = time
        self.data = data
    def __eq__(self, other):
        'For comparison'
        equal = self.time == other.time
        # equal if there is a one in both things at the same bit position
        equal = equal and bool(int(self.data, base = 2) &
                               int(other.data, base = 2))
        return equal
    def __lt__(self, other):
        'For sorting'
        return self.time < other.time
    def __str__(self):
        return '({}, {}, {})'.format(self.name, self.time, self.data)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '({}, {}, {})'.format(self.name, self.time, self.data)
```

Use the csv module to make a list of `Thing`'s and sort them (by `time`):

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
things = [Thing(**row) for row in reader]
things.sort()
```

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [itertools.combination](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to compare thing's with the same `time`.  Put things that are equal in a set.

```
results = set()
for key, group in itertools.groupby(things, key = operator.attrgetter('time')):
    print key
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(group, 2):
        if a == b:
            print '\t{} is duplicate of {}'.format(a, b)
            results.add(a)
            results.add(b)
```

This results in

```
>>> 
0x34
    (tg, 0x34, 1111) is duplicate of (k, 0x34, 0100)
    (tg, 0x34, 1111) is duplicate of (c, 0x34, 0001)
    (tg, 0x34, 1111) is duplicate of (d, 0x34, 1111)
    (k, 0x34, 0100) is duplicate of (d, 0x34, 1111)
    (c, 0x34, 0001) is duplicate of (d, 0x34, 1111)
0x54
>>> results
set([(tg, 0x34, 1111), (c, 0x34, 0001), (d, 0x34, 1111), (k, 0x34, 0100)])
>>>
```

---

Not sure if I understood the specs - the following *dataset* produces zero duplicates:

```
s = '''name,time,data
tg,0x34,0010
ab,0x54,1011
k,0x34,0100
c,0x34,0001
e,0x34,0000
d,0x34,1000'''
```

---

You probably want to keep duplicates for different times separate so keep them in a dictionary using the time as the key.

```
results = collections.defaultdict(set)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(things, key = operator.attrgetter('time')):
    print key
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(group, 2):
        if a == b:
            print '\t{} is duplicate of {}'.format(a, b)
            results[key].update((a,b))
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for great example with code attached above! I learnt something new today: itertools.combination functions.